# Automatically add a numeric value to the SQL Server database after the expiration of a certain date( Date will vary )

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I can't figure out how to implement this as I am new to ASP.NET. I am building a Library Management System in ASP.NET using C# and SQL Server 2008 R2.

There will be a "Book Issue" and "Return Date" respectively for each book.

Now my question is: how can I enable the application to automatically add a numeric value to the SQL Server database on the expiration of the `Return Book` date (note that the `return book` date will vary)?

SQL Server Job scheduling was suggested but I think it does not meet my requirements as in my case the date after which the job will be executed differs i.e the `Book Return` date for each book.

Any suggestions will be helpful.

Thanks

Comment: When scheduling was suggested, it sounds like they meant, run a job each day to figure out which books return dates have expired, then set the value appropriately.  This does sound like a scheduling task, unless you want an on insert or on update trigger.

Answer (score 2):

Create a SQL Agent job that runs at midnight every day.  Configure the job to run a query that sets the "numeric value" for all loans where the return date was "yesterday".  Use a date function in your query to calculate "yesterday", such as `DATEADD(DAY, -1, CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE()))`.  This means that it doesn't matter what date the job runs, it will always match the right Book Return Date and process the right loans.